# Where can I find a wig for Clannad?

Tags: clannad

I've been wanting to cosplay as Nagisa Furukawa for a long time but I could never find a wig.

Comment: Check out this proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/79160/cosplay-and-fancy-dress There you might find all answers to your cosplay questions (if it gets enough users)

Answer (score 2):

Good places to search are Japanese shops that sell new or used cosplay items (or shops that import official cosplay items from Japan to whatever country you live in); the websites of people who make and sell handmade cosplay items; Halloween costume websites; and sites with many sellers such as Cosplay.com's [Marketplace](http://www.cosplay.com/marketplace/index.php), Yahoo Japan Auctions, Etsy, Amazon Marketplace sellers, and eBay.

Nagisa's hair is almost identical to that of Kinomoto Sakura of Cardcaptor Sakura, which is an extremely popular character, so if you search for Sakura wigs, you will find ones that can work.